# How to know which indexes are always used

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google App Engine - Tracking which indexes are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651609/google-app-engine-tracking-which-indexes-are-used)

I have an app with several indexes, i would like clean all indexes not used, to get better performance.

Now I have a index.yaml with just indexes needed but i'm not really sure it is right because sometimes, datastore needs composite indexes or maybe i have make a mistake.

The real question is how to know wich indexes are used?

*The big problem is if i remove an index used, the time to remove it is very, ...very long and it is same to build.*

Answer (score 1):

The process used to be:

1. clear out index.yaml on your local development copy of the app
2. run a covering set of tests on the SDK (doesn't have to cover every line of code, just every query, which makes it easier to write these tests than to write a set of unit tests for the components of the app)
3. upload the new index.yaml, which is now complete since the development server automatically adds any index that it uses to the file
4. vacuum indexes.

It's possible this has changed. I haven't used GAE for a while and the developers have a habit of introducing new, better ways of doing things. But the old ways pretty much always continue to work.

[Edit: found a dupe, so assuming this answer is still the state of the art, go upvote [Nick Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651609/google-app-engine-tracking-which-indexes-are-used/3651774#3651774) instead of me]

Comment: Ok, but no information about composite index needed by the production environnement?

Comment: @sahid: why does the production environment need different indexes from the development environment? As far as I know, a given query requires the same indexes everywhere, but as I say I might be out of date.

Comment: The development environment doesn't _need_ indexes at all, though you can specify a command line flag to make it pretend it does. It generates exactly the indexes needed in production.

Comment: @Nick: Do you mean "doesn't need indexes" in the sense that it uses indexes, but generates anything it wants to use on demand? I was thinking of that as "needing indexes", just not needing them to be pre-specified by the app. Or do you mean "doesn't need indexes" in the sense that the dev server actually searches the whole table on every query? If the latter, then is it just a verification step that prevents the dev server from, for example, including multiple non-equal comparisons in a query?

Comment: @Steve The dev server doesn't use indexes - they're generated purely so they're there for the production environment. Yes, you could probably make minor modifications and the dev server would be able to execute queries with multiple inequalities, though that would be a bad idea.

Comment: @Nick: Sure, I'm not planning to actually do it, just correct my very vague notion of what the dev server is up to :-)

Comment: @Steve Just checking - some people try to do really weird things with App Engine. ;)